# How to resgister IWebRequestCreate in mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd like to do a web request to an internal API, I've found most people use [HTTPCLient](https://dotnet.github.io/api/System.Net.Http.HttpClient.html) but I just don't want to hardcode a dependency in my controller or create a wrapper for now, so I decided to try IWebRequestCreate.
At the time to run the application I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'System.Net.IWebRequestCreate' while attempting to activate
>   'Project.Web.Main.Controllers.HomeController'.

that's because I haven't registered that service at the start up, so when I tried to register webrequest, turns out that's an abstract class and I'm forced to use the create method, so any ideas?

I'm thinking about registering like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IWebRequestCreate>(x=>x.GetService(???));
```

my controller is very basic:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IWebRequestCreate _webRequest;
        private readonly AppOptions _options;

        public HomeController(IWebRequestCreate webRequest, IOptions<AppOptions> settings)
        {
            _webRequest = webRequest;
            _options = settings.Value;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var wr = _webRequest.Create(new Uri(_options.ApiHost));
            var response = wr.GetResponseAsync();

           //TODO map the response to a DTO
            return View();
        }
    }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up by creating an implementation for IWebRequestCreate:

```
 public class MyWebRequest: IWebRequestCreate
    {
        public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
        {
            return WebRequest.Create(uri);
        }
    }
```

and registering the dependency in the project configuration:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IWebRequestCreate),typeof(MyWebRequest));
```